# Is it safe to call getrawmonotonic() in Linux interrupt handler?

Tags: linux-kernel, timestamp, interrupt

I did some research online, and people suggest using getrawmonotonic to get timestamp in kernel. Now I need to get time stamp in ISR, just wondering if it's safe. The Linux kernel version is 2.6.34.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is safe to use `getrawmonotonic` in interrupt handler.

Implementation of that function (in `kernel/time/timekeeping.c`) uses *seqlock* functionality(`read_seqbegin()`, `read_seqretry` calls), which is interrupt-safe, and `timespec_add_ns()` call, which is just arithmetic operation.